# reconstruct the decomposed image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, wavelet

I am applying Wavelet decomposition of 4 Level but [image]while reconstructing the same RGB image its coming in 3 parts. code is as below

```
fullRecon = cAA{nLevel};
for iLevel = nLevel:-1:1,
  fullRecon = idwt2(fullRecon,cHH{iLevel},cVV{iLevel},cDD{iLevel},'db1');
end
figure, imshow(uint8(fullRecon)),title('Full Recont Image');
```

**The forum is not allowing me to upload any image so please follow the below link**

http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/195203-reconstruct-the-decomposed-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
fullRecon = reshape( fullRecon, size(fullRecon,1), [], 3 );
```

Comment: Thank You its working but extra lining is coming Plz check the below link


http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/195203-reconstruct-the-decomposed-image

Comment: @Luky what is the new question?

Comment: Actually its combining the image but some extra lining is coming ...

Please check this link


http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/195203-reconstruct-the-decomposed-image

Comment: @Luky these artifacts exists in the original image and has nothing to do with the `reshape`ing of the result. It looks like some boundary effects, but it is difficult to answer without looking at the code that generated this result. You might consider asking a new question.